# How much functionality is there in an .xlsm file embedded in html

Tags: html, excel

If I were to embed a macro-enabled workbook on a web page, would the users be able to:

1) Run the macros and if so

2) Would the Macro run on the server or the user's machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Macros won't run. 2003 xls files with macros in them were unable to run in html format as well.